# IFS(Internal Field Seperator) generic for Linux and AIX

Tags: linux, ksh, aix, ifs

Is there a generic code for IFS to work to not to treat whitespace as new line,

On Linux below works just fine

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

However on AIX it doesn't work properly and I have to use below

```
IFS='
'
```

Is there a code which I can use on both Linux and AIX for ksh.

Comment: I would use `NL=$(printf '\n')`, but it isn't that easy: newlines are trimmed from to end; so I suggest this: `NL=$(printf '\n.'); NL=${NL%?}`

Comment: Your AIX approach should work on any system, including bash or ksh on Linux.

Comment: How do you use it? When you are trying a `for field in ...; do`, you can avoid the problem of the spaces by switching to `while read -r field; do .. `.